# WebStorm - change the menus and toolbar background color

Tags: javascript, colors, menu, webstorm

I was able to change the colors in the code part in the editor, but I can't find anywhere how to change the background color of the menu and toolbar in WebStorm.

Anybody knows where is it? I'm trying to make a Visual Studio Code like coloring. (although can't be 100% same :( )

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not configurable -- no GUI for that, at all.

You either use one of the bundled GUI Themes (`Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance`) or install custom theme as a plugin (like you have right now: "Afterglow Theme" or "Material Theme UI") -- and check what they can offer.

P.S. You can check those plugins (their source) and create your own that would either use desired color or provide such customisation option.

Comment: Thanks! With the Afterglow Theme it's quite nice